# Angular check if entity value true or false

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I can display the value of an entity:

```
<span>{{entity.var}}</span>
```

I want to display part of the content only if the entity value = true. I checked the Angular variable in HTML code but didn't succeed:

```
<span *ngIf="entity.var ==='true'">display text</span>
```

What is the syntax for?

Thank you.

Comment: *ngIf accepts a boolean. Your value is already a boolean, therefore you don't need to compare it to a boolean. "boolVar === true" is the same as "boolVar"

Answer (score 2):

It should work

```
<span *ngIf="entity?.var">display text</span>
```

Comment: Does it check True or false? Is there a method to check entity.val value?

Comment: If entity.val is a boolean, your check shouldn’t have quotes around ‘true’..

Comment: And how can I check not boolean values?

Comment: If you want to check not boolean values so it should work the way you did. Which type are you trying to test ?